# Can't play next song in queue

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

The bot is wrote to shift the queue and play the next song but on Node v12.16.2 it doesn't do what I believe it should do. It worked on an older node version but I would like to stay on Node v12.16.2 and get it to work.

Here is a code snippet:

```js
dispatcher.on("finish", () => {
    if (!serverQueue.songs.length == 0) {
        serverQueue.songs.shift();
        play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was a code issue, as you may see I had the shift on the wrong line, just saw this and thought I'd come back to update just in case anyone had the same thing. Rookie error on my part.